# Leitura de pastas se tornaram lentas após uso do "npm install"

Tags: osx, npm

Após instalar alguns módulos através do comando `npm install`, abrir uma pasta no Finder ou em uma IDE (Atom ou Sublime) se tornou algo muito penoso e demorado.

Parece que o problema pode estar relacionado com o tamanho da pasta, mas ao se comparar com outras pastas isso não faz sentido, pois mesmo abrindo outras pastas com uma quantidade enorme de aplicativos não ocorre o mesmo.

Abaixo está a imagem do carregamento, que leva bem mais de 40 segundos para "verificar", mas somente para uma pasta em específico após o uso do `npm install`

[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]

Comment: Tente isso, um amigo teve esse problema, e me indicou esse link: http://osxdaily.com/2015/04/17/fix-slow-folder-populating-cloudkit-macosx/

Comment: Esta solução resolveu o meu problema: Percebi que na pasta que eu estava tentando ler, não havia permissão de leitura para "staff", "everyone". Modifiquei e tudo resolveu.

Comment: Parece uma pergunta legal que encaixa em "problemas enfrentados por programadores". Calebeaires, será que pode publicar uma resposta abaixo detalhando a solução. Obrigado!

Comment: Se conseguiu resolver, poste como resposta abaixo. Você pode aceitar sua própria resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solução:** modificar permissões das pastas para que seja possível a leitura sem a autenticação do usuário no OSx. Isso é feito como descrito na imagem abaixo no qual consta a janela de informações da pasta problemática.

Uma solução que fiz foi a sugerida pelo Guilherme Lima nos comentários abaixo, mas também adicionei permissões gerais de leitura. Elas não existiam. Após este procedimento, a leitura da pasta foi quase que imediata. Veja na imagem abaixo com detalhes no staff e everyone:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]